# Open multiple instances of Python .py files/code with CMD (command prompt) with .bat extension

Tags: python, cmd.exe, prompt

I try to open multiple instances of Python .py files/code with CMD (command prompt).
So, I made a file with .bat extension, and I run it every time I want to open multiple .py files/code.

This is the code from .bat file

```
@echo off
"e:\Carte\BB\App-one.py" 
"e:\Carte\BB\App-two.py" 
"e:\Carte\BB\App-three.py" 
"e:\Carte\BB\App-four.py" 
"e:\Carte\BB\App-five.py"
```

The only problem I have is that when I click the first time, and Python is close, cmd will open only the first "App-one.py"

So, I have to run twice the .bat file in order to open all Python files/codes.

**Now, I want to open all .py files from ONE CLICK, not twice.**

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command to run each item.

```
@echo off
start "cmd1" "e:\Carte\BB\App-one.py" 
start "cmd2" "e:\Carte\BB\App-two.py" 
start "cmd3" "e:\Carte\BB\App-three.py" 
start "cmd4" "e:\Carte\BB\App-four.py" 
start "cmd5" "e:\Carte\BB\App-five.py"
```

```
Start a program, command or batch script, opens in a new/separate Command Prompt window.

Syntax
      START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]

Key:
   title       Text for the CMD window title bar (required.)
   path        Starting directory.
   command     The command, batch file or executable program to run.
   parameters  The parameters passed to the command.
```